# How to print attribute of object instead of object in view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently using the [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem to model tagging on my rails application. In my new tag view I have a field where the user can enter a parent tag for the tag that is to be created. After saving the new tag, editing the tag will display the parent field as #. How can I display the parent tag's name in the field instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed a to_s function for my model and things displayed correctly.

```
def to_s
  self.name
end
```